# Concatenate two list by applying an operation in pairs using java stream

Tags: java, filter, java-stream, concatenation

I have two lists of Boolean and I need to concatenate them by applying an AND operation to the elements with the same index, I'm expecting to get a list of Booleans that contains the result of doing the operation in pairs.

```
public List<Boolean> concatenate(List<Boolean> l1, List<Boolean> l2) {

    return l1.stream()
                .flatMap(e1 -> l2.stream()
                                .filter(e2-> l1.indexOf(e1) == l2.indexOf(e2))
                                .map(e2-> e1&&e2))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The size of the resulting list will be `l1.size()*l2.size()` so the filter inside the second stream is filtering anything.

Comment: Do you must use streams? It is just making your life complicated. Why don't you use classical loop?

Comment: Can you put sample input and expected output?

Comment: l1 : {true,false,true}, l2 : {false,true,true} -> {false,false,true}

Comment: what if the two list have different number of elements? what do you expect then?

Comment: I'm always expecting that they have the same size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Boolean> l1 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(true, false, true));
List<Boolean> l2 = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(false, true, true));

List<Boolean> l3 = IntStream.range(0, min(l1.size(), l2.size()))
                            .mapToObj(i -> l1.get(i)&&l2.get(i))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());

// [false, false, true]
```

You can use `IntStream.range()` to iterate over both the lists at once and `.mapToObj()` to convert the `&&` to `Boolean` and `.collect()` to store it in a new `List`.

You can simplify the range to `.range(0, l1.size())` if you know for sure that both of them are of the same size.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily do it using com.google.guava library (version 21 and above)

```
public List<Boolean> concatenate(List<Boolean> firstList, List<Boolean> secondList) {
        return Streams.zip(firstList.stream(), secondList.stream(), (a, b) -> (a && b))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the filtering is that you use `indexOf` which always return the first occurrence of the element, since you have Booleans.

Given that the size of the two lists are equal, you can go with the classical way:

```
public List<Boolean> concatenate(List<Boolean> l1, List<Boolean> l2) {
    List<Boolean> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int index = 0; index < l1.size(); index ++) {
        result.add(l1.get(index) && l2.get(index));
    }
    return result; 
}
```

Comment: The OP has asked for a solution with streams. This is probably not what the OP is looking for.